# Get Quack Overflow back after you press "I hate this duck"

Tags: support, quack-overflow

I know this might be a strange question, but I thought Quack Overflow was cool and I pressed "I hate this duck" and it disappeared. How can I get it back?

Comment: Arrr, time zones...

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Oh that was for April 1st! I indeed got it too early too!

Comment: The interactions with the duck don't seem to vary. Once you've seen it once you've seen it all.

Comment: yes but sometimes you realize you've made a mistake and now you miss them and want them back

Comment: Post sadly edited by `@honk` rather than `@quack.`

Comment: Some more quacks would've made a great quack :D

Comment: @user276648 Same.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can get it back by removing the `quack` cookie.

Comment: I see no duck and no cookie today :-(